# How would I escape HTML in SpringBoot's @PathVariable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring 4.2.5 and I just want to escape the HTML in the URL if present. Using JSON deserializer is affecting the values of RequestBody/Param as well, but I don't want other values to be changed. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML you are seeing the path variable on the http request - and how you your controller method is annotated to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I need to use PropertyEditorSupport class to escape the HTML in the PathVariable and implement JSON deserializer for the RequestBody.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's URL builder escapes html in parameters automatically:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html

If you're talking about html in the spring Rest controller,  a filter or Jackson configuration should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, if I am sending a POST request using an API, say, 'localhost:8081/api/{id}' then I want to validate just the path variable i.e. {id} and not the request body. Jackson deserializer for String is affecting all the values which I don't want to happen. Since I have many APIs/controller implemented I am looking for a solution which would apply to all and just validate/escape the HTML in the path variable.